# Loading a Maps API site in a Native Android Application

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to follow the example from google:

> http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/android_v3.html

Using the example files from their SVN repo:

> (http)gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/articles-android-webmap/

But although it seems to compile and export it fails; can someone sanity check that its not just me this fails for and any hints as to if its a quick thing to fix, I've been prodding it with try/catch for the last 2 hours to no avail.

Thanks :o)

**Forgot to add**
It Compiles and Uploads to the emulator (and to my phone) but running it just results in

```
The Application WebMapActivity (process com.google.android.examples.webmap) 
has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again. [Force Close]
```

Comment: What does your error? It bugs at the compilation or there is nothing happends? If there are error can you writte them here please?

Comment: Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine the Java stack trace associated with the "Force Close" dialog. That stack trace should tell you where things are going wrong. Here is a link to another map sample, one I know works: http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Maps/NooYawk/

Comment: The Google example is a WebView passing the GPS data to the Page via a JavaScript method. 
I actually own that book :o) so i'll have a poke through and see if theres anything about the webview; I've tried the normal Android-Maps api but I agree with the google article in that its easier to manage and update when the apps online, and the app is simply an interface to that :o)
Tar

Answer (score 1):

Filtered it down to

```
private void setupWebView() {
        /*
            final String centerURL = "javascript:centerAt("
                    + mostRecentLocation.getLatitude() + ","
                    + mostRecentLocation.getLongitude() + ")";
            webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            // Wait for the page to load then send the location information
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    webView.loadUrl(centerURL);
                }

            });*/
            webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
            webView.loadUrl(MAP_URL);
    }
```

Bit easier to filter out the actual issue when you know which bit doesnt work thanks to CommonsWare for the great book, poking through that and test-code that ACTUALLY WORKS made it a bit easier to work out what was going on. And thanks for the debug info :o)